# How can i make my simple 3D objects look mathematically correct?

Tags: java, 3d

I wanted to try drawing 3D Objects like a cube etc. and i got it working farely well. The problem is, that the cubes right side and left side are different in size and looks, even though, they should look the same. The second problem is, that the cube keeps glitching out, when i draw behind the *camera*.
The code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{
  public GameFrame(){
    this.add(new GamePanel());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.pack();
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  new GameFrame();  
  } // end of main
} // end of class GameFrame



public class DimensionPoint {
  int x,y,z = 0;
  public DimensionPoint(int x, int y, int z){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
    }
  public int getXprojected(int length){
    return length == -z ? x*length/(length+z+1) : x*length/(length+z);       //Temporary, because you can't divide by zero
    }
  public int getYprojected(int length){
    return length == -z ? x*length/(length+z+1): y*length/(length+z);
    }
  public int getZ(){
    return z;
    }
} // end of class Point



import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
  static final int width = 800;
  static final int height = 800;                                                                                                                     
  DimensionPoint[] cube = new DimensionPoint[8];
  int pos = 75;
  public GamePanel(){
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    this.setBackground(Color.gray);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    setCube(100,400,10,200,cube);
    }
  
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    draw(g);
    }
  public void draw(Graphics g){
      g.setColor(Color.black);
      if (cube[5].getZ() > -pos+9) { // This is also only temporary. When you change the size of the cube, it sometimes still glitches out, or dissapears before leaving the screen
        drawCube(g,cube);
        }
    }
  public void setCube(int anfangX, int anfangY, int anfangZ,int size, DimensionPoint[] p){
    p[0] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX,anfangY-size,anfangZ);
    p[1] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX,anfangY,anfangZ);
    p[2] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX+size,anfangY-size,anfangZ);                                
    p[3] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX+size,anfangY,anfangZ);                                   
    p[4] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX,anfangY-size,anfangZ+size/10);
    p[5] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX,anfangY,anfangZ+size/10);
    p[6] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX+size,anfangY-size,anfangZ+size/10);
    p[7] = new DimensionPoint(anfangX+size,anfangY,anfangZ+size/10);
    }
  public void drawCube(Graphics g,DimensionPoint[] p){
      g.drawLine(p[0].getXprojected(pos),p[0].getYprojected(pos),p[1].getXprojected(pos),p[1].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[0].getXprojected(pos),p[0].getYprojected(pos),p[2].getXprojected(pos),p[2].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[0].getXprojected(pos),p[0].getYprojected(pos),p[4].getXprojected(pos),p[4].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[1].getXprojected(pos),p[1].getYprojected(pos),p[3].getXprojected(pos),p[3].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[1].getXprojected(pos),p[1].getYprojected(pos),p[5].getXprojected(pos),p[5].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[2].getXprojected(pos),p[2].getYprojected(pos),p[6].getXprojected(pos),p[6].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[2].getXprojected(pos),p[2].getYprojected(pos),p[3].getXprojected(pos),p[3].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[3].getXprojected(pos),p[3].getYprojected(pos),p[7].getXprojected(pos),p[7].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[4].getXprojected(pos),p[4].getYprojected(pos),p[5].getXprojected(pos),p[5].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[4].getXprojected(pos),p[4].getYprojected(pos),p[6].getXprojected(pos),p[6].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[7].getXprojected(pos),p[7].getYprojected(pos),p[6].getXprojected(pos),p[6].getYprojected(pos));
      g.drawLine(p[7].getXprojected(pos),p[7].getYprojected(pos),p[5].getXprojected(pos),p[5].getYprojected(pos));
    }
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ }
} // end of class GamePanel
```

I tried minimizing the code as far as possible, and i hope the mistake can be found. Thank you for the advice.